# Ruby on Rails tutorial test failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am on chapter 8 of Michael Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial book, and I am stuck on the sessions helper test from chapter 8. I am not sure why, but it keeps failing, here is the output:

```
  1) Failure:
SessionsHelperTest#test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil[/home/robert/sample_app/test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-#<User id: 762146111, name: "Michael Example", email: "michael@example.com", created_at: "2015-10-16 20:15:11", updated_at: "2015-10-16 20:15:12", password_digest: "$2a$04$GeN8/eE5hXsYwZA9AMATQeOpe5MyN2rAglt8di5kTch...", remember_digest: "$2a$04$wsaTKG4lu5.vTc3Sb62tB.QCWtfpo6ifSvXcPW0FNVE...">
+nil
```

Here is a link to my bitbucket repo: https://bitbucket.org/colcrunch/sample-app/src/efcdda6964160121a707094b873954750f852bb2?at=log-in-log-out

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be better to include the relevant part(s) of the code and indicate where its failing rather than linking the entire project. Otherwise we'd have to clone and run the project, pick through your code, etc.

Comment: I dont know what is actually causing it to fail... the sessions_helper_test.rb is exactly the same as the one in the examples, that it says should work, my guess would be that it is somewhere in the changes here: https://bitbucket.org/colcrunch/sample-app/commits/343630d42479149ac460c565d9139ac1d10a1503?at=master but I am not sure.

Comment: Given the name of the test method, it seems the `current_user` is not what you're expecting it to be. So that could be either a problem with your `current_user` method, or maybe the test itself is improper. Side note, from a quick look at the `current_user` method, it seems to return nothing if there's no session or cookie, but the test method seems to imply it should; is this how its supposed to be?

Comment: In your sessions_helper.rb file line 12 is incorrect, change from:

`cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = user.remember_token`
to `cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token`

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the tutorial as a guide, in your sessions_helper.rb file change line 12 from:

```
cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```

to

```
cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found the fix.  Some of the suggestions to remove 'signed' from line 12 are incorrect.  This creates a security flaw in the program.

Here's how to resolve the issue:

In your sessions_helper.rb file change line 22 from:

`if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])`

to

```
if user && user.authenticated?(cookies.signed[:remember_token])
```